# Cant find the pixel with bitmap because its have different rgb values on different devices

Tags: c#, bitmap, pixel

I tried to find a specific pixel with rgb color but the same pixel have different colors on different devices, on python with pyautogui for image search i can use confidence to handle that.

Anyone know a solution for that? I would be very grateful if someone could find a solution.

Comment: "Confidence" is just color values within a certain tolerance range. In other words, take the `Math.Abs(actual value - desired value)` and see if that number is less than a certain tolerance (like within 10-15). If all channels are within tolerance, then you are "confident" it is the "same color".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From my comments:

> "Confidence" is just color values within a certain tolerance range. In
> other words, take the Math.Abs(actual value - desired value) and see
> if that number is less than a certain tolerance (like within 10-15).
> If all channels are within tolerance, then you are "confident" it is
> the "same color".

Here's a quick example:

```
  public static bool colorConfidence(Color targetColor, Color actualColor, int confidence) {
    int deltaA = Math.Abs(targetColor.A - actualColor.A);
    int deltaR = Math.Abs(targetColor.R - actualColor.R);
    int deltaG = Math.Abs(targetColor.G - actualColor.G);
    int deltaB = Math.Abs(targetColor.B - actualColor.B);
    return (deltaA <= confidence) && (deltaR <= confidence) && (deltaG <= confidence) && (deltaB <= confidence);
  }
```